# Running "responsive_images:dev" (responsive_images) task >> Unable to compile; no valid source files were found

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to set grunt, I have already download GraphickMagick and ImageMAgick.
My OS is LINUX MINT.
When I try to run $grunt I get the following error:

```
Running "responsive_images:dev" (responsive_images) task
Unable to compile; no valid source files were found.
Unable to compile; no valid source files were found.
```

My current directory is **/project-server**:

```
project-server/images/
project-server/img/
project-server/node_modules/
project-server/Gruntfile.js
project-server/package.json
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
responsive_images: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      engine: 'im',
      sizes: [{
        name: 'small',
        width: '30%',
        suffix: '_small',
        quality: 20
      },{
        name: 'large',
        width: '50%',
        suffix: '_large',
        quality: 40
      }]
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      src: ['*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
      cwd: 'images/',
      dest: 'images/'
    }]
  }
},
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['responsive_images']);
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "project-server",
"version": "0.1.0",
"devDependencies": {
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
"grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
"grunt-responsive-images": "^1.10.1"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So,

```
 src: ['*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
      cwd: 'images/',
      dest: 'images/'
```

Attention to **cwd** value, it says that my current directory is /images, so whenever he tries to find the value for **src**, it will search under /images. BUT my files {.png,.jpeg} arent under /images.

Then, all I had to do was to *comment* the **cwd** value. And it worked fine!